# How to insert member function in vector? Getting Compilation error

Tags: c++

How to insert member function in pair of vector where one pair is member function, do I need to use std::bind to bind the member function ?

```
class Notification
{
  std::vector<std::pair< std::string, std::function<void(const std::string&
          , std::string)>>> NotificationReq;
public:
  Notification()
  { 
      NotificationReq.push_back(std::make_pair("NTFY_OCIS_REBOOT", TestReboot)); 
  }
  void TestReboot(const std::string& , std::string)
  {   
  }

};
int main()
{
   Notification temp;
}
```

I m getting compilation error: reference to non-static member function must be called. Please can some one help me out to solve this issue?? Thanks

Comment: Did you even bother attempting to solve this yourself? all I did was google your error message... seriously, don't be so lazy.

Comment: Thanks Amit . I tried but still getting the same issue. Please can you   tell me what should i write for this line   NotificationReq.push_back(std::make_pair("NTFY_OCIS_REBOOT", TestReboot));